# Counting number of visible entries using jsTree

Tags: leaflet, javascript, plugins

I'm displaying a tree via jsTree within a jQuery dialog box and that is running fine. Now I want to resize the dialog box depending on the number of visible entries of the tree.

Resizing is not the problem but I need the number of visible lines.

Example: https://wambachers-osm.website/emergency/idx402.jsp

this shows 2-16 lines and the box is too big.

btw: page is still in development. some features not working yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it.

```
...
isVisible=2 // default for my tree
...
var tree = $.jstree.reference('#jstree');
...
$('#jstree').on('after_open.jstree after_close.jstree', 
 function (e, data) {
    isVisible = countVisibleItems(tree);
    return;
 }).jstree();

function countVisibleItems(tree) {
   var data = tree._model.data;
   var visible = 2; // default (base + overlay)
   $.each(data, function(index, value) {
     if (value.state.opened) visible = visible+value.children.length;
   });
   return(visible);
}
...
```

Comment: you should mark this (your own) answer as accepted so that the question is marked as answered.

Comment: sorry, missed that